# Need SQL or Lambda tutelage for SQLite

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, lambda, windows-store-apps

I've been searching for SQLite query examples. Those that I was able to find in SQL wouldn't compile, because various methods and classnames were not recognized (namely Open(), SQLiteDataReader, and SQLiteDatabase).

Those in Lambda I don't quite understand. For example, this:

```
public Task<List<Platypi>> GetAllLocationsAsync()
{
    return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath).Table<Platypi>().ToListAsync();
}
```

...presumably returns every record in the Platypi table via the returned List. But I don't want them all, I want to limit/filter the records; this is a start, I guess:

```
private async Task<List<Platypi>> GetLocationsForPeopleAndTimeRange(List<string> DuckbillIds, DateTime EarliestToShow, DateTime LatestToShow)
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    var query = conn.Table<Locations>().Where(x => x.DuckbillId // ? what now ?
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

...but I don't know how to construct the Where() clause. I need to query for all records where DuckbillId is one of the values in DuckbillIDs, and where the DateTime field is between EarliestToShow and LatestToShow. IOW, pseudo-SQL would be something like:

select * from Platypi where duckbillId in DuckbillIds and DateVal between EarliestToShow and LatestToShow inclusive

I would prefer some working examples for basic SQL Selects, Inserts, Updates, and Deletes (CRUD operations); second-best would be Lambda, whose syntax appears quite convoluted to me.

LINQ would be okay, too.

### UPDATE

I found some samples on SQLite-Net's page (http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/) which led me to this, which at least compiles:

```
public List<Locations> GetLocationsForPlatypiAndTimeRange(List<string> PlatypiIds, DateTime EarliestToShow,
                                                         DateTime LatestToShow)
{
    var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(SQLitePath);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (String s in PlatypiIds)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("{0},", s));
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // remove the superfluous trailing comma
    return
        db.Query<Locations>(
            "Select * from Locations Where PlatypusId in (?) and SentTimeLocal >= ? and SentTimeLocal <= ? Order by SentTimeLocal",
            sb.ToString(), EarliestToShow, LatestToShow);
}
```

Comment: `.Where(x -> x.Duckbillid == someValue);`  If you're merely returning a single record, consider using `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Where`.

Comment: If memory serves, `async` and `await` already perform the necessary gyrations to make your query asynchronous, so you do not need `ToListAsync`, but merely `ToList`.

Comment: If you are checking for an item in a list, use `Contains`.  The "between" just needs two conditions in your `Where`.

Comment: Several examples for Linq can be found here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Sure it's a real question; some of the comments here are not real answers, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code samples I'm asuming you're using [sqlite-net](http://nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net). Try taking a look at its [readme](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) and [documentation](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki). There are couple of working samples using SQL syntax that should get you going.

I'm not sure which samples you were trying out but the class names you are mentioning are definitely not part of sqlite-net, they sound as if they were from the [SQLite ADO.NET provider](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite).

Comment: Yes, I believe you're right about them being from the ADO.NET provider.